# Flash doesn't work with Fogger

Tags: flash

I recently installed **Fogger** but it isn't using `flash plugin`. Of course I have flash installed, but I can't watch YouTube videos without HTML5 enabled.

Please someone tell me how or what can I do? I want **Fogger** to use flash.

Answer (score 6):

You can make Flash Player work in Fogger by executing following commands in Terminal:

```
cd ~; mkdir foggerflashfix; cd foggerflashfix
wget https://fpdownload.adobe.com/get/flashplayer/pdc/11.2.202.491/install_flash_player_11_linux.i386.tar.gz
tar -zxvf install_flash_player_11_linux.i386.tar.gz
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/i386
sudo cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/i386
sudo apt-get install nspluginwrapper
sudo nspluginwrapper -i /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/i386/libflashplayer.so
sudo nspluginwrapper -v -a -n -i
cd ~; rm -r foggerflashfix
exit
```

After that, your Flash content should load correctly.

**[Source](http://answers.launchpad.net/fogger/+faq/1992)**

Comment: Oh! My God! You're a freak!!! This really works :D hahaha You made my day, Thank you very much! :D

Comment: The URL is dead, and here is the new URL as of 2013 ... wget http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/pdc/11.2.202.280/install_flash_player_11_linux.i386.tar.gz

Comment: @allen-west Fixed. :)

Comment: @user154831 the link does not work for me.

Comment: @rajlego The URL has been updated.